# Any way to get the x,y,w,h of the document selection (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, selection

I've been trying to find a way to get the coordinates of the document current selection (Dom-selection).

I need this because I want to be make the selection of the document drag-able. (I want to avoid the native behavior of browsers drag&drop because you have to hold still a little in order to initiate a d&d (at least with Chrome)).

So far I haven't been able to come up with anything,

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do take a look at Rangy range and selection library here: [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) - And in particular this example they've put up: [Selection Position Demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/position.html)

Comment: @KspR what do you mean - document selection? Do you want to select some content on page and get selection coordinates (like in file-managers when you select multiple files) or something with cursor selecting like when you select text string?

Answer (score 0):

Hate reply with a link but this is the best option for you
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

If you don't mind libraries, try jquery with the function "offset"

$("#yourSelection").offset().left (or .right)